# Consumindo Json de um aquivo

Tags: angularjs

bom dia,eu criei um arquivo JSON e estou com dificuldades listar os dados a partir dele, eu consigo do controller, mas gostaria que fosse exibido a partir do json, como devo proceder ?

Comment: Podes mostrar o código onde precisas usar o JSON?

Comment: estou estudando angular e criei um aquivo JSON e gostaria que exibisse na tabela como fazer isso

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow, Luciano! Por favor [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/212027/edit) sua pergunta, e inclua o código de onde você está tendo problema (quanto mais informações você der, mais fácil/rápido conseguirá uma resposta) - faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conhecer melhor o site, e leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sobre como elaborar uma pergunta mais completa.

Answer (score 0):

A requisição para ler dados de um arquivo JSON funciona basicamente como uma requisição do tipo GET para uma API de uma aplicação de backend.

Você pode fazer dentro de uma factory:

```
function recuperar(){
    return $http.get("api/arquivo.json").then(function(resposta){
        service.arquivo = resposta.data;
    });
};
```

Onde "api/arquivo.json" é o endereço, a partir da raiz do seu projeto, de onde está o arquivo JSON.